# Multiple errors when try to makemigrations relating to missing SQL package

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I am new to Django as well as StackOverflow, so my apologies in advance. I'm not really sure how to format the terminal text...

When I run "python manage.py makemigrations [myappname]":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/weiqian/Documents/WCP/feature_01/sitedir/appuser/models.py", line 6, in <module>
class Tasks(models.Model):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I read other similar questions, and so I tried "pip install MySQL-python" and many other versions thereof, and I got this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
/private/var/folders/vr/sgvcx9_n1hq4gtcknn7ln7d00000gn/T/pip-build-ON_V7M/mysql-python/
```

From there, I tried updating setuptools, and got this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'
```

I'm stuck... Thoughts? Many thanks!

Comment: You should be using a virtualenv and load your django project inside of that..

Answer (score 0):

The last error means you don't have enough permissions to carry on with the task, you need to run the command with `sudo`.

The package that's missing is `MySQL-python`. You can install it using either setuptools or pip:

`sudo easy_install MySQL-python` `sudo pip install MySQL-python`

I advise you to install pip and use it to manage your project's dependencies: `sudo easy_install pip`. After installing pip you can simply `sudo pip install packagename`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I have pip installed, and I followed the "sudo easy_install pip" again just to make sure. Same error with the "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1...